# how to create factor analysis data in R

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I recently learnt about factor analysis and now I wanted to test it by generating samples in $X$ like $$X = FL^T + N$$
where $F$ is a matrix with in each row the factors for one sample, $L$ is the factor loading matrix and $N$ contains the noise for each sample in it's rows.

In `R`, I translated this to

```
# L <- some fix values
# diag(PSI) <- some fix values
nrSamples <- 1000
F <- MASS::mvrnorm(nrSamples, mu=rep(0, times=ncol(L)), Sigma=diag(1, ncol(L)))
N <- MASS::mvrnorm(nrSamples, mu=rep(0, times=nrow(L)), Sigma=PSI)
X <- F %*% t(L) + N
```

When trying to apply factor analysis now to reconstruct $L$ - using `factanal(X, factors=ncol(L))`, I do not get a very good result.

I went through the entire assumptions from factor analysis (to check if I made a mistake in creating this model) when I realised that the noise and factors that I created are not independent, i.e. $F^T N \neq \boldsymbol{0}$. I know I should not expect a perfect zero matrix, but I get values up to 104 which is very non-zero in my humble opinion.

My question is now whether it would be possible to generate $F$ and $N$ in such a way that they are (more) independent in `R` and if not, how I could generate data in any other way that is well-suited for factor analysis, i.e. data for which I know at least $F$ so that I can experiment a bit with the parameters and could for instance try to reconstruct the original $F$ by finding the correct rotations etc...

Thanks in advance